# I am getting an "Error: Can't Open Display" in this very basic C code, but I don't understand why

Tags: c, linux, binary-tree, binary-search

So I did a bit of C programming a while ago and basically forgot it all lol but anyways I started doing this "C Refresher" thing I found online and was following this binary search tree example kinda loosely and ran into an error. Once I compile it and run it, it says "Error: Can't Open Display". I am running this code on some kinda Linux server in school. Anyways, here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0 

typedef struct Node {
  int value;
  struct Node *left;
  struct Node *right;
} Node; 

void add (Node *node, int value)
{
  if (value < node->value) {
    //left side 
    if (node->left == NULL) {
      Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
      newNode->value = value;
      newNode->left = NULL;
      newNode->right = NULL; 
      node->left = newNode;
    } else {
  add(node->left, value);
    }
  } else {
    //right side 
    if (node->right == NULL) {
      Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
      newNode->value = value;
      newNode->left = NULL;
      newNode->right = NULL;
      node->right = newNode;
    } else {
      add(node->right, value);
    }
  }
}

int search(Node *node, int value)
{
  if (node == NULL) {
    return FALSE;
  } else if (node->value == value) {
    return TRUE;
  } else {
    if (value < node->value) {
      return search(node->left, value);
    } else {
      return search(node->right, value);
    }
  }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Node root;

  root.value = 23;
  root.left = NULL;
  root.right = NULL; 

  add(&root, 5);
  add(&root, 50);
  add(&root, 8);
  add(&root, 2);
  add(&root, 34); 

  if (search(&root, 23)) {
    printf("23 lives in the tree.\n");
  } else {
    printf("23 does not live in the tree.\n");
  }

  if (search(&root, 42)) {
    printf("42 lives in the tree.\n");
  } else {
    printf("42 does not live in the tree.\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The code might seem long but it is actually pretty basic. I think I coulda cut some of the code out before pasting it here but I figured I would leave everything in in case I took out something vital to the problem.

Also I thought it might have something to do with the Node thing so in my `main` method I put a quick `printf("hi");` before the `Node root;` to see if that would make a difference but it still gave me the same error. And I have another program on my account on this school server and that program has some `printf` statements and it runs just fine.

I tried Googling the problem but all this weird Linux threads came up and I couldn't really understand it. My computer is Windows but I did all this coding in a program called emacs that I got to through a program called PuTTY that lets me connect to the school Linux server.

Also I compiled it with `gcc -o tree tree.c`.

Sorry for all the writing, I was just trying to give as much information as possible. Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: How are you actually executing it? Are you trying to run it in a debugger?

Comment: "Cannot open display" is an X11 error message. You're not using X at all in that piece of code. Are you sure you're running what you think you're running?

Comment: what does `env` gives you under DISPLAY variable ? default should be `:0.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you invoking it like "./tree" or just "tree". It looks like you are trying to run a gui application over ssh. To see which application try connecting with "ssh -XY HOST" if you are on a linux machine. Then you should see an application launching.

Comment: or type `which tree`to figure out what it's actually trying to execute when you type `tree`

Comment: OMG THANK YOU! I guess `tree` is a Linux command or something, and I was just typing in `tree` and it was interpreting it as the command rather than my program. OMG thank you so much this has been bugging me all day and just put a halt in all my progress but yeah when I type in `./tree` it works just fine!

Comment: A note of caution if you are using "ssh -XY HOST" : The manpage for ssh says that the flag Y "Enables trusted X11 forwarding.  Trusted X11 forwardings are not subjected to the X11 SECURITY extension controls." and further up in the manpage there's more info such as "An attacker may then be able to perform activities such as keystroke monitoring.".